# Receive Forbidden message when request Uber receipt API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uber-api

Document endpoint

`https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/references/api/v1-requests-request_id-receipt-get`

My application already has FULL ACCESS for `request_receipt`

[image: FULL ACCESS permission]

However, in my Rails application, when I request to endpoint API  at: `/v1/requests/my-request-id-here/receipt` I receive the full message like this:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7f8738f833f8 parsed_response={"message"=>"Forbidden", "code"=>"forbidden"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx"], "date"=>["Wed
, 02 Nov 2016 14:31:37 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "content-length"=>["42"], "connection"=>["close"], "x-uber-app"=>["uberex-nonsandbox", "migrator-uberex-optimus"], "strict-transport-sec
urity"=>["max-age=0"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"]}>
```

Do you have any suggestion? The Uber API for developer is poor!

Comment: Are other endpoints working? If not, it might just be a configuration issue (e.g. not sending the appropriate token/secret).

Comment: `GET /v1/me` and `GET /v1.2/history` work fine. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely you did not request the new scope when you authorized the user and got the access token. Access tokens are limited to the scopes approved by the user (so even though it is enabled in the dashboard) you need to pass the 'request_receipt' scope when authenticating the user.

See more details in the authentication guide: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/authentication/introduction#step-one-authorize

If you create a new access token with the scope all should work as expected.

Comment: I try with other accounts but still not work. For sure, I check the received scopes after step 3 (Get an access token), and the received scopes include `["profile", "history_lite", "request_receipt", "all_trips"]`

Comment: Hey Leo, I think the issue here may be that the request you are trying to get the receipt for was not made through your app (guessing this is likely as your screenshot above shows no `receipt` endpoint). I will follow up with you directly. Cheers!